# A boa pratica é usar \n para pular linhas ou usar um print() sozinho?

Tags: python, string

Sei que adicionar `\n` em uma string fará com que uma nova linha seja iniciada, mas quando eu quiser pular uma linha eu deveria usar `\n` no final/começo de uma string ou deveria colocar um print() sozinho?

Por exemplo:

```
palavra = input("digite uma palavra: ")

for letra in palavra: 
  print(letra, end=" ")

print("Isso é um teste")
```

nesse caso digamos que eu queira separar `palavra` de `"isso é um teste"` por duas linhas.

Eu deveria fazer `print("\n\nIsso é um teste")` ou colocar dois prints antes de `print("isso é um teste")` ?

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta muito estranha, pq na prática não faz diferença. Acredito que `\n` seja uma melhor opção porque é mais enxuto e sem prejudicar a legibilidade do código

Comment: Que é mais compacto eu sei, mas e se por acaso eu precisar pular 3 linhas? dai eu teria que fazer \n\n\n. Não sei pra vc, mas assim me parece mt esquisito.

Comment: É só fazer `print('\n' * 3)` - vai imprimir 3 `\n` (e mais o `\n` que o próprio `print` já inclui no final)

Comment: hmmm, boa ideia. Nunca que eu teria pensado nisso kkkk

Comment: Depende da situação. Haverá situações que será necessário utilizar um `"\n"`. Em outras situações será necessário o `"\n * m"` (m = inteiro) e, em outras situações será necessário `"print()"`.

Comment: Estou a meia hora pensando nessa pergunta. A achei interessante .

Answer (score 3):

teste de tempo mostra que usar `'\n'` é mais rápido

```
python3 -m timeit 'print();print();print()'
20000 loops, best of 5: 16.2 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit "print('\n\n\n')"
20000 loops, best of 5: 11.9 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit "print('\n'*3)"
20000 loops, best of 5: 11.9 usec per loop
```

`'\n\n\n'` e `'\n'*3` não apresenta diferença significativa

Answer (score 0):

Nesses casos eu sempre me preocupo em fazer da forma que torne o codigo mais legivel,
caso você precise apenas pular duas linhas usar:

```
print("\n\n Meu texto")
```

Nao fica ruim, mas caso o texto seja algo muito maior, quebrar em alguns prints pode ser a melhor saída

```
print("Bem vindo ao meu programa")
print("Selecione a opção abaixo")
print("1")
```

Comment: Vlw pela dica. <3